# Do I have to purchase Radiant Defense in app content again on a new device?

Tags: android, radiant-defense

I installed Radiant Defense on my Asus Transformer tablet and have purchased all the locked items. I expected to reuse these purchased items on my Android phone but it seems to be I need to repay for that. Is this true?

If it is, I really hate this kind of purchase :)

Comment: I seem to experience the same issue on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8. All logged in using the same Live ID, but I find no way to recover profile, game progress, or purchases between devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The review [here](http://www.tested.com/news/44018-google-play-roundup-april-23/) states purchase can be restored on a different device:

> I was able to access my purchased content on multiple devices by going into the settings and using the “Restore Purchases” button